# Cloudera Metric Template Location or Create Custom

Tags: cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I am trying to create custom metric template to reflect on chart builder. Also i need to know the configuration files where i can make changes for metrics. Is this possible or Cloudera metric opensource.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the template used by Ambari when creating alert notifications. An `alert-templates.xml` file ships with Ambari. This file contains all of the templates for every known type of notification, such as EMAIL and SNMP.

More details and [examples](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.7.4.0/managing-and-monitoring-ambari/content/amb_customize_notification_templates.html).